# $G$ is a tree $\iff G$ contains no cycles, but if you add one edge you create exactly one cycle - is my proof correct?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

$G$ is a tree $\iff G$ contains no cycles, but if you add one edge you create exactly one cycle

---

Could anyone please be so kind to check my proof? That would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

My proof:

'$\rightarrow$' Assume $G$ is a tree. Then by definition it is connected. Furthermore, there is a unique $u, v$-path for every $u,v \text{ in } G$. For arbitrary $u$ and $v$, let this path be $u=u_1\rightarrow u_2\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow u_k=v$. Assume $\nexists$ an edge $e=\{u_i,u_j\}$ for some vertices $u_i, u_j \text{ } (j>i)$ in this path. Now add this edge $e=\{u_i,u_j\}$. Then we can follow the original $u,v$-path until we arrive at $u_j$ and then return to $u_i$ via $e$. Hence this is a cycle.

'$\leftarrow$' Assume $G$ contains no cycles but if you add one edge you create exactly one cycle. To prove that $G$ is a tree we only need to prove connectedness, since it is already given that $G$ contains no cycles. Reason by contradiction. Assume that $G$ is not connected. Then $\exists u \exists v \text{ }(u\neq v)$ in $G$ s.t. $\nexists$ an edge $\{u,v\}$. Add this edge. This will not create a cycle. But this contradicts our original assumption. Hence $G$ must be connected, and thus $G$ is a tree.

Comment: One concern that I have is that I have not explicitly incorportated the fact that you create *exactly one* cycle. I do think it is implicitly there though. Or should that be taken care of in more detail (if so, how?)?

Comment: Looks pretty good, except in the $\leftarrow$ direction you need to choose your $u,v$ more carefully.

Comment: @vadim123 Thank you. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'more carefully'? What should be changed?

Comment: You need $u,v$ to be in different components.  You're also right about the "exactly one" in the $\rightarrow$ direction.

Comment: @vadim123 Thank you for your help. Could you please show me how this should be written down? Also the ''exactly one'' part please, as I could not figure out how I should include that in my proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove "exactly one" in the $\rightarrow$ direction, suppose the addition of $(u,v)$ created (at least) two cycles.  Both must include $(u,v)$ else they were cycles before.  However, we  now can go from $u$ to $v$ along two different paths in the tree, a contradiction.

In the $\leftarrow$ direction, if $G$ is not connected, choose $u,v$ from different components.  Then adding $(u,v)$ cannot create a cycle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! What exactly do you mean with 'different components'?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!