# Adding an edge to a tree creates a cycle - is my proof correct?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I saw you answered similar questions here, but I wanted to know if 
I can prove the theorem (= adding an edge to a tree creates a cycle) 
also like this:

It is known that the definition of a *tree*, is that it's-

1. connected,

2. with no cycles,

3. and with **$n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges**.

Also, it is known that a *cycle* has-

* equal number of vertices and edges, suppose- 
**$n$ edges and $n$ vertices**.

Therefore, when we add one edge to a tree, the tree contains now $n$ edges $((n-1)+1),$ and it is exactly the number of its vertices, so it contains a cycle now.

Is this whole proof correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cycle contains the same number of edges as vertices. But not every graph with this property is a cycle, so your final statement is unjustified.

Some six-vertex graphs with six edges you can find on [The House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/) that aren't cycles are below (there's plenty of other examples if you'd like more).

[image]
[image]
[image]

You may notice that all of these graphs *contain* a cycle, and in fact that's generally true, but this is precisely the statement you have to prove.

One approach might be to first find a subgraph which has minimum degree $2$, and then find a cycle inside this subgraph in the usual way.

Also, a final nitpick: usually, only the first two properties you gave (connected and has no cycles) are the *definition* of being a tree. The third property, of course, is likely to be something you prove about trees fairly early on, starting from that definition.

Answer (score 2):

Informally, you can argue as follows. Any two vertices in a tree are connected by exactly one path. Add an edge e connecting v1 and v2. Then you can reach v1 from itself by following the edge e and the existing path from v2 to v1.

Comment: Valid, though at the stage where you're proving that adding any edge to a tree creates a cycle, you're likely to want a proof for your first assertion as well.

Comment: Yes,  Wikipedia uses the path condition as the definition of a tree but if we are starting from the definition in the question, we need to prove equivalence

Comment: "Any two vertices in a tree are connected by exactly one path". This can be proved as the following: let arbitrary vertex pair be $(u,v)$ and the path number between them be $p(u,v)$. "connected" implies $p(u,v) \ge 1$. "with no cycles" implies $p(u,v) \le 1$. So we have $p(u,v)=1$.

Comment: BTW, "exactly one path" implies only one cycle is created after adding one edge because 1. trivially this cycle must contain $e$ otherwise the original graph is not one tree. 2. $e$ can be only concatenated with the path $p(v_1,v_2)$ in the original graph to construct one cycle. This is also shown in [this QA](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/420543/1059606).